# expect script error interact: spawn id exp4 not open

Tags: bash, shell, tcl, expect

I have a script that it work well as i expect but at the end, when it terminates, produces this error:

```
interact: spawn id exp4 not open
    while executing
"interact"
    (file "./pippo.sh" line 8)
```

The code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

# Spawn Python and await prompt
spawn mono OpenSim.exe

expect_background {
    "Now recording all stats to file every {0}ms" { sleep 10 ; send "stats record stop\n" ; expect "Stopped recording stats to file." {sleep 5 ; send "quit\n"} }
}

interact
```

Answer (score 1):

This is normal if, when your `expect_background` sends `quit\n`, the spawned process exits. This will close the file descriptor (*spawn id*) connecting expect to the process, and so `interact` will fail when it tries to continue reading (or writing) the process.

You can suppress the error by adding a line to your background command that detects end-of-file and exits when it does:

```
expect_background {
  "Now recording all stats to file every {0}ms" \
  { sleep 10 ; send "stats record stop\n" ; \
    expect "Stopped recording stats to file." \
    { sleep 5 ; send "quit\n"; \
      expect eof exit } } }
```